# Foundation footer is not full page width

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have created a website using Foundation 5 and am having some trouble with a few of my pages footer not filling the width of the page. Other pages work fine and the footer fills the page perfectly. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my footer for one of the pages I am having trouble with.

```
<footer class="footer">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-5 columns">
         <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" /></a>
         </div>
         <p class="footer-links">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="aboutus.html">About</a>
            <a href="staff.html">Staff</a>
            <a href="comingsoon.html">Online Giving</a>
            <a href="http://vimeo.com/firstag">Sermon Videos</a>
            <a href="contactus.html">Contact</a>
         </p>
         <p class="copywrite">Copywrite © 2015 First Assembly of God, Lincolnton</p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">
         <ul class="contact">
            <li>
               <p><i class="fi-marker"></i>328 May Avenue<br>P.O. Box 457<br>Lincolnton, Georgia 30817</p>
            </li>
            <li>
               <p><i class="fi-telephone"></i>Phone | 706-359-7237<br>FAX | 706-359-6638</p>
            </li>
            <li>
               <p><i class="fi-mail"></i>office@firstaglincolnton.org</p>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-3 columns">
         <p class="about">CONNECT WITH US</p>
         <p class="about subheader">Please visit our social media accounts to keep up with current events.</p>
         <ul class="inline-list social">
            <a href="http://twowhoagree.blogspot.com/"><i class="fi-social-blogger"></i></a>
            <a href="http://vimeo.com/firstag"><i class="fi-social-vimeo"></i></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/FirstAGofLC"><i class="fi-social-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/First-Assembly-of-God-Lincolnton/169771389824660"><i class="fi-social-facebook"></i></a>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with css. With out knowing your css code, it is difficult to understand the issue.

Comment: If you do not show us a picture or give us a fiddle, how are we to tell if its off by 1px or 100px? What specifically is your issue?

Comment: If you are only off by about 16px; I would say set `body{margin: 0px;}` but we can just guess for now.

Comment: Thank you all for responding so promptly. This is my first time using this site so bear with me as I attempt to give you all of the information you need. I will create a jsfiddle for you all as soon as I am back at my computer (I am responding via iPhone at this moment). To go ahead and answer your question Adam, my footer seems to be mimicking the width of other segments of my page rather than filling the width of the page. I cannot give you the exact dimensions at this moment but will give you all what I can as soon as possible. Thank you all again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to have full width row:

```
.full-width {
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   max-width: initial;
}
```

Then merge `footer` with the first `div` and add the class `full-width`:

Old

```
<footer class="footer">
   <div class="row">

   [...]

   </div>
</footer>
```

New

```
<footer class="row footer full-width">

[...]

</footer>
```

Working example: [CodePen link](http://codepen.io/Akarienta/pen/QjYdee)